# How to get the data from a custom propertie that is in a group on an custom control on an Xpage?

Tags: custom-controls, xpages, custom-properties

I'm working on a custom control that has custom properties.

If I want to use the value of a property it is very easy.
For the value of the property "maptype" I can use compositeData.maptype
But how do I do this wit groups?

For example I have a goup called "Marker" and there can be multiple of them.
Each marker has five properties: "address", "title", "layer", "infotext" and "icon".
How do I access for example the value of title on the third marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the group of properties is interpreted as com.ibm.xsp.binding.PropertyMap java class. The multiple instances are interpreted as java.lang.ArrayList class. Knowing this I would try

```
compositeData.Marker[2].address
```

for simple data binding. Or

```
compositeData.Marker.get(2).get('address')
```

for accessing via pure javascript.

Comment: Thank you Denny, I solved the problem with your help end some aditional "'". This worked for me:

var test = [
  #{javascript:"'" + compositeData.marker[0].address + "'"}  
];
alert(test);

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to use it. It is just a collection with properties that you can iterate. One way could be to use it inside a repeat control. This is an example how you could use it:

```
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30"
                value="#{javascript:compositeData.Marker}"
                var="rowMarker">

                <xp:label id="lbladdress"
                    value="#javascript:rowMarker.address}">
                </xp:label>
                <xp:label id="lbltitle"
                    value="#javascript:rowMarker.title}">
                </xp:label>

            </xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Thank you Ferry, your example is about how you can loop in a repeater, but I want to loop in Javascript. I'm looking for something like compositeData.Marker[2].title but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop, you can just use:
    for(marker in compositeDate.Marker){
        marker.title;
    }